# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} f_n(t) dt \neq \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt $

Tags: general-topology

What is example of $\{f_n\} \in C[0,1],f\in C[0,1]$ such that $f_n \to f$ point wise but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} f_n(t) dt \neq \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt $

Comment: You can make it so that all the $f_n$ have integral $1$ but they are going pointwise to $0$, by making a sequence of successively taller and thinner triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $f_n$ so that $f_n(0) = 0$, $f_n(1/n) = n$, $f_n(2/n) = 0$ and interpolate the functions linear inbetween. This sequence of function converges pointwise to $0$, but all the integrals have a value of $1$.

Comment: @Macavity You're right, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I thought almost same function, but was taking $f_n(0)=1$...

Comment: Same thing: $f_n(x)= 0$ if $x< n$, $f_n(x)= 1$ if $n\le x\le n+ 1$, $f_n(x)= 0$ if $x> n+1$.

Comment: @user247327: This is not a counterexample. Note that the functions are supposed to be from $C([0, 1])$.

Answer (score 2):

Try $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 2n^2x & x\leq1/2n\\2n-2n^2x & 1/2n<x\leq 1/n\\ 0 & x>1/n.\end{cases}$$